# difference between various pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between the following two codes:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
```

and

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};
```

Comment: no difference, except way we write it and length of code may increase in first case.

Comment: One compiles, the other doesn't? Or are you asking why this is the case?

Comment: 1st code doesn't compile.

Comment: both codes do complie...my question is that do they have same or different meaning?

Answer (score 0):

There's *a lot of difference*. Certainly, the first code won't compile since there's no such type `node`, but there's a type `struct node`.

In your case the correct variant is the second one.

Comment: Mine is because you're answering a different question, whose answer is not the same as the answer to OP's question.

Comment: @juanchopanza, oh sh*t, I've misread the question. I'll edit it ASAP. LOL